# Http Callout to Rest API from apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout

How to `send request` and `get response` from server when working with `Rest` API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 Http http1=new Http();
 HttpRequest req1=new HttpRequest();
 req1.setendpoint('URL');
 req1.Setheader('String','String');
 req1.setmethod('POST'); //you can also SET method `GET` with Get there is no need of req1.setbody()
 req1.setbody(string);
 HttpResponse res1;
 res1 = http1.send(req1);
 String str=res1.getbody();
```

Answer (score 3):

The details of making HTTP callouts in Apex are found in the developer.force.com wiki pages here:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Comment: Hi Aisha. Welcome to SFSE. As you appear to be new I'd like to invite you to read a little about etiquette and use of stack exchange. The expectations for interaction are a bit more structured than a discussion forum. So when you get a chance, take a look here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour .

Answer (score 0):

These Is How You Can Send A request or get Response

```
public class pincode {

public string x {get;set;}
    public PageReference click() {

   http p = new http();// invoiking Http Class
httprequest req= new httprequest(); //Invoking RestRequest
req.setEndpoint('http://pin-codes.in/api/pincode/500072');//Setting Endpoint
req.setMethod('GET');// Setting Method 
httpresponse res = new httpresponse();
res=p.send(req);
system.debug('-------'+req.getBody());
x= res.getbody();// Catching Response 
        return null;
    }

}
```